# Xcode 15 problems with previews in KMM projects

Tags: xcode, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I experience a problem where previews of SwiftUI stop working. Only the preview feature fails, I can still run the simulator.

The problem is reported as following:

> Task :shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode FAILED
>
> error: /Users/ ... .app/Frameworks: Operation
> not permitted
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode'.
> Cannot access output property 'destDir' of task ':shared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking in the Gradle documentation.
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/ ... .app/Frameworks: Operation not permitted

If I create a project everything works fine, but If I came back later this problem starts to occur.

Next day: Now the Simulator also stopped working and Xcode does not show the error details, just "Failed to create directory '..../Frameworks'.

Comment: Try to disable User Script Sandboxing and stop gradle deamon as Timofey suggested here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-62745/iOS-application-build-is-failing-if-script-sandboxing-option-is-enabled-in-Xcode

Comment: Alas is it not solving the problem for me.

Comment: Which version of kotlin and Android Studio do you have?

Comment: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 RC 1 and Kotlin 1.9.10
(by the way AS is able to build and start the simulator while Xcode can't)

Comment: I had a very similar problem and I solved it as in the comment above, but I use AS Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a whole day trying to figure this one out. Thanks to @kojot's comment above with a link to youtrack I finally got it sorted. For completeness here is the solution:

**Disable script sandboxing**

1. Select the target in Xcode.
2. Select the `Build settings` tab
3. Under `Build options` look for `User script sandboxing` and set it to No or `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = NO;`
4. Run `./gradlew --stop` in your project folder (This is the one I was missing)
5. Build and run!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing working at the moment is to recreate the project. Not an elegant solution for sure, hope the problem will be fixed in one of the next updates.